# Sending a json object with jetty in java

Tags: java, json, client, jetty

I can't figure out why nothing happens.

I'm trying to write a java program that sends a json object to a jetty server.
The server is already written(by someone else,its an project) and only excepts certain json objects. But he doesn't get anything from my program.

```
public class client {
    final static String HOST = "localhost";
    final static int PORT = 3000;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

        String URIString = "ws://" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "/servlets";
        URI uri = URI.create(URIString);
        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();

        JSONObject js = new JSONObject();

        js.put("toke","hallo");



        Clientsocket clientsocket = new Clientsocket();
        try {
            client.start();
            Future<Session> fut = client.connect(clientsocket, uri);

            clientsocket.getSession().getRemote().sendString(js.toJSONString());;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

public class Clientsocket extends WebSocketAdapter {

    //private static final Logger LOG = Log.getLogger(Clientsocket.class);

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode,String reason)
    {
        super.onWebSocketClose(statusCode, reason);
        //LOG.info("Websocket Close:{}  - {} ", statusCode,reason);
    }


    @Override
    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session) 
    {
        super.onWebSocketConnect(session);
        //LOG.info("Websocket Connect: {}", session);

    }


}
```

error message when started:

```
2018-06-22 14:26:43.789:INFO::main: Logging initialized @257ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
java.lang.NullPointerException


[both classes: clientsocket, client][1]
```

Comment: not enough to work with.  where's the rest of the stracktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't wait for the connect to complete.

```java
Future<Session> fut = client.connect(clientsocket, uri);

Session session = fut.get(); // wait for connect to complete (or throw exception)

session.getRemote().sendString(js.toJSONString());
```